# replace_na with tidyselect?

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyselect

Suppose I have a data frame with a bunch of columns where I want to do the same `NA` replacement:

```r
dd <- data.frame(x = c(NA, LETTERS[1:4]), a = rep(NA_real_, 5), b = c(1:4, NA))
```

For example, in the data frame above I'd like to do something **like** `replace_na(dd, where(is.numeric), 0)` to replace the `NA` values in columns `a` and `b`.

I could do

```r
num_cols <- purrr::map_lgl(dd, is.numeric)
r <- as.list(setNames(rep(0, sum(num_cols)), names(dd)[num_cols]))
replace_na(dd, r)
```

but I'm looking for something tidier/more idiomatic/nicer ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we need to dynamically do the `replace`ment with `where(is.numeric)`, can wrap it in `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dd %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric), replace_na, 0))
```

---

Or we can specify the `replace` as a `list` of key/value pairs

```
replace_na(dd, list(a = 0, b = 0))
```

which can be programmatically created by `select`ing the columns that are `numeric`, get the `names`, convert to a key/value pair with `deframe` (or use `summarise` with 0) and then use `replace_na`

```
library(tibble)
dd %>% 
  select(where(is.numeric)) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ 0)) %>%
  replace_na(dd, .)
```

Comment: the second is the one I wanted to avoid (since it's hard to do with `tidyselect`/programmatically), the first is the solution I was looking for (vector-wise application).  Can't accept for a little while longer.